# Paypal checkout. Customize "Cancel and return to" text.

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm developing a marketplace which allows users to list items for sell. When an user buys something my application calls the PayPal API and sends the buyer to the Express Checkout page. I've been able to change the logo on the header and some other fields, however I'm not able to change the text "Cancel and return to -selleremail-". I would like that instead of the -selleremail- it showed my website name. According to what I been reading so far, you need a PayPal business account to change this text, however, I've seen that for instance on Etsy, in the same checkout page, they have managed to change this text, even if they, like me, aren't the receivers of the money.

Any idea?